# What is the best way to crawl the webpage to get keyword related meaningful content with the help of Java?

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, jsoup

I tried with JSOUP something like the code below but it doesn't seem to work out well with multiple keywords and keywords that appear multiple times in a webpage. 
Apart from that, when pages like http://www.dataplumbing.com/ are concerned, the navigation links like 'Home','Blog','data science central' etc etc (ones in black) and the copyright in bottom of page and terms of service at the bottom of page are also visited as text using jsoup though tags belonging to it are removed. 
All I need to do is to get keyword related content from a single webpage.Any better way possible other than jsoup is also welcomed. Thanks in advance.

```
       for(int x=0;x<urls.size();x++)
        {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urls.get(x)).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36").referrer("http://www.google.com").ignoreContentType(true).timeout(60*1000).get();
        String outputString = Jsoup.clean(doc.html(), Whitelist.basic().removeTags("ul","li","a","span","img"));
        outputString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(outputString);
        System.out.println(outputString);
        Document doc1=Jsoup.parse(outputString);
    String result=doc1.text();
        BreakIterator iterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
iterator.setText(result);
int start = iterator.first();
ArrayList<String> ls=new ArrayList<String>();

for (int end = iterator.next();
    end != BreakIterator.DONE;
    start = end, end = iterator.next()) {

  ls.add(result.substring(start,end));
  }



for(int y=0;y<urlkeys.size();y++){
         for(int a=0;a<ls.size();a++)
         {
        if(ls.get(a).toLowerCase().contains(urlkeys.get(y).toLowerCase()))
        {
        System.out.println(ls.get(a));

        }

            } 
        }

    }
```

Comment: `get keyword related content`? can you more specific?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the method [`text()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#text--), you are getting

> the combined text of the element and all its children
>   with whitespace is normalized and trimmed.

In your case, you are using `doc.text()`, so you get all of the text for the entire document.

You'll have to be more specific about which parts of the webpage you want, but scraping blog posts can be achieved with [CSS selectors](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax):

```
// retrieve web page source code
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dataplumbing.com/").get();

// use css selectors to find the blog entries
Elements blogs = doc.select("article .entry-title > a");

// iterate the blogs and extract the title and link
for (Element blog : blogs) {
    String blogTitle = blog.ownText();
    String blogLink = blog.absUrl("href");
    System.out.println(String.format("title=%s url=%s", blogTitle, blogLink));
}
```

**Output**

```
title=Data Preparation & Modeling for Campaign Optimization url=http://www.dataplumbing.com/blog/data-preparation-modeling-for-campaign-optimization
title=Demand for IoT Sensors in the Automotive Industry Drives IoT Sensors Market url=http://www.dataplumbing.com/blog/demand-for-iot-sensors-in-the-a
utomotive-industry-drives-iot-sens
title=Data Lakes Still Need Governance Life Vests url=http://www.dataplumbing.com/blog/data-lakes-still-need-governance-life-vests
...
```